# Element already child of another element - PivotItems

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvm-light

I'm currently struggeling with a crash that I don't really know the origin of or the solution for.

I have a ViewModelLocator with my VM which was registered in the constructor (

```
ctor { ... SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TabMainViewModel>(); }
public TabMainViewModel TabMainVm => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TabMainViewModel>();
```

This VML is then used by the XAML as Static Resource

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}, Path=TabMainVm}"

<Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding PivotItems}">
```

And the TabMainViewModel looks like this:

```
public TabMainViewModel(MenuPivotFactory factory)
{
    PivotItems = new ObservableCollection<PivotItem>(factory.PivotItems);
}

public ObservableCollection<PivotItem> PivotItems { get; set; }
```

And the factory is injected by the ServiceLocator (also registered) and it just creates a list of PivotItem's

```
/*NavigationHelper*/
private static readonly IDictionary<Type, Type> ViewModelRouting
        = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
        {
            {typeof(MonitorViewModel), typeof(MonitorView)},
            {typeof(RouteViewModel), typeof(RouteView)},
            {typeof(MapViewModel), typeof(MapView)}
        }
public static Page GetView(Type viewModel)
    {
        return (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(ViewModelRouting[viewModel]);
    }

/*Factory*/
new PivotItem
    {
        Header = new TabHeader {Label = "Monitor", Glyph = "\uE121"},
        Content = NavigationHelper.GetView(typeof(MonitorViewModel))
    },
```

I hope this makes my object creation process somewhat clear.

Now I can navigate between the different PivotItems without problem. But when i navigate away, and then press the back button sometimes it works and sometimes I get thrown into the App.g.i.cs with the error mentioned in the title: Element is already child of another element.

While debugging I get to the point where the View calles the get method of the VMs PivotItems property and then throws this error. So I assume that it has something to do with the Views in the PivotItems or something.

How do i create the objects correctly so this error is not thrown and I can navigate between the Pivot Page and other pages without crashing?

Comment: Are you adding / removing pivots? Or is it always the same set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've reproduced your problem:

[image]

This is because your `ItemsSouce` is collection of `PivotItem` control: `ObservableCollection<PivotItem>`. When you go back to the `TabMainPage`, in the `public ObservableCollection<PivotItem> PivotItems { get; set; }`, the same `PivotItem`s are second time added to `Pivot`.

Here is a solution, in the `OnNavigatingFrom` method of `TabMainPage`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    this.DataContext = null;
    base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
}
```